# paypal asp.net integration

Tags: asp.net, paypal

How to use express checkout using PayPal API in ASP.NET

Comment: If you are looking the latest solution, checkout this demo --> https://techtolia.com/PayPal

Answer (score 1):

at first, you have to set account in the sandbox to do your tests : 
https://developer.paypal.com/
The doc of aPI is here : https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference 
A possible way is to use :

SetExpressCheckout
GetExpressCheckoutDetails
DoExpressCheckoutPayment

You can store the TransactionId received and process : DoReferenceTransaction and DoCapture in order to set a recurring payment.

So, please set up your question explicitely and I can send you sample of code. The API is realy big.